# How to find cause of Visual Studio settings editor exceptions?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, settings.settings

I have a project for which I can't open the settings editor in Visual Studio 2015. If I double-click the Settings.settings file or select the Settings tab in the project properties, the pane doesn't show the usual editor; just the message "The method or operation is not implemented.".

How can I go about finding the cause? Is there some way to see more details of the exception to help figure out what is not implemented? I last worked on the project in VS2013; could opening it in VS2015 have changed something to cause this?

If I create a new project and overwrite its Settings.settings file with mine, it opens fine in that project, but won't open in my existing project.

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  There isn't any real way that you could not discover the underlying problem by yourself when you follow that guidance.

Comment: The same thing happened to me, but it worked again after I restarted Visual Studio. Weird.